# Приложение из Android Studio запускается, а с устройства нет

Tags: java, android-studio, android, activity

Здравствуйте,помогите разобраться в чем причина..
Пишу приложение в Android Studio.

Запускаю кнопкой Run. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На подключенном устройстве все запускается. Ошибок нет, работает как надо. :
[image: Фото запущенного приложения]
................................................................................................................................................................
Но если я запускаю это приложение с телефона нажатием по значку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То не запускается. Сначала белый экран. Потом темный и все... висит..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я предполагаю что это как то связано с тем что я в setContentView() помещаю класс DrawSurface(this). Потому что с R.layout.activity_circle не возникает проблем.
Вот код:

```
public class CircleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new DrawSurface(this));
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_circle);
    }
}
```

Класс DrawSurface:

```
public class DrawSurface extends SurfaceView implements     SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private DrawThread thread;
private String TAG = "LOG";

public DrawSurface(Context context){
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    thread = new DrawThread(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}


public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry){
        try{
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        }catch(InterruptedException e){

        }
    }
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        thread.touchX = event.getX();
        thread.touchY = event.getY();
        Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + event.getX() + ",y=" + event.getY());
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Класс DrawThread:

```
public class DrawThread extends Thread{
private double speedMoveX = 1;
private double speedMoveY = 1;
private double Y0 = 0;
private double Angle = 1;
private Random rand;
private double gravityForce = 1;
private int newAngle = 0;
private Bitmap myBitmap;
private long prevTime;
private float X=0;
private float Y=0;
protected float touchX=-40;
protected float touchY=-40;
private Paint paint;
private Paint paintScore;
private int currentScore = 0;
private int textSize = 54;

private boolean running = false;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private DrawSurface drawSurface;
private String LOG_TAG = "LOG";

public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, DrawSurface drawSurface){
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    rand = new Random();
    Angle = rand.nextInt(25);
    paint = new Paint();
    paintScore = new Paint();
    paintScore.setTextSize(textSize);
}

public void setRunning(boolean running){
    this.running = running;
}
public void updateCord(){

    X += speedMoveX * Math.cos(Angle * Math.PI / 180);
    Y += speedMoveY * Math.sin(Angle * Math.PI / 180);

    if (Y > Y0+9.8){
        speedMoveY += gravityForce;
        Y0 = Y;
    }
    if (X > 420){
        X = 420;
        speedMoveX = -speedMoveX;
    }
    if (X < 60){
        X = 60;
        speedMoveX = -speedMoveX;
    }
    if (Y >= 760){
        Y = 760;
        speedMoveY = -speedMoveY;
    }
    if (Y < 60){
        Y = 60;
        speedMoveY = -speedMoveY;
    }
}

private boolean isHit(){
    boolean hit = false;
    if(touchX > X-60 && touchX < X+60 && touchY > Y-60 && touchY <Y+60){
        hit = true;
    }
    return hit;
}

public void run(){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Starting game loop");
    long tickCount=0;
    Canvas canvas = null;
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(8);


    while (running){
        tickCount++;

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = now - prevTime;
       /* if (elapsedTime > 1){
            prevTime = now;
            updateCord();
        }*/
        try {
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            if (canvas == null)
                continue;
            canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
            Log.d("LOG onDraw()", "onDraw()");
            canvas.drawText("touchX = " + touchX + ", touchY = " + touchY, 10, 20, paint);
            canvas.drawText("Score:",200,50,paintScore);
            canvas.drawText(currentScore+"" ,360,50,paintScore);
            canvas.drawCircle(X, Y,60, paint);
            if (isHit()){
                currentScore++;
                paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                Angle = rand.nextInt(20);
                X = rand.nextInt(330);
                Y = rand.nextInt(760);
            }
            else{
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                touchX=-40;
                touchY=-40;
            }
        }finally {
            if (canvas != null){
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Game loop executes"+tickCount+" times");
}
}
```

Вот AndroidManifect.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="circle.denis.com.circle" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".CircleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Вообще не стоит делать экраном приложения вьюху, так обычно поступают при разработке игр, и если у вас при запуске из ADT всё норм, то это наврятли связано с запуском через кнопку, а если и связано, то тут уже проблемы могу быть с манифестом. А ошибку не кидает? Если кидает, то покажите лог. А если у вас не возникает проблем при добавлении Layout, то нафига вы шаманите, просто добавьте layout, который будет содержать вашу въюху и всё

Comment: Вижу у вас в коде, что вы не передаёте атрибуты в вашей View, а это необходимо. DrawSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){ super(context, attrs); }

Comment: @BORSHEVIK Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: покажите манифест. Может быцть так, что вы запускаете из студии одну активити, а из меню - другую

Comment: Добавил манифест. Там одна активити...

Comment: Ситуация немного прояснилась. Когда я закрываю свое приложение на телефоне нажимая на кнопку(стрелочка назад). Потом захожу в телефоне в Настройки->Приложения->Сторонние->Мое приложение(О приложении)->Остановить(нажимаю кнопку). Выскакивает сообщение "Принудительная оcтановка" -> жму Ок.  После такого закрытия приложения, если я его опять запускаю с телефона,то все Ок запускается. А если так в ручную не останавливать, то кидает ошибку при запуске. Но так же не годиться   в ручную каждый раз лезть в настройки и его останавливать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Проблема решена!;)**

В классе **DrawSurface** в методе **public void surfaceDestroyed()**:

```
public class DrawSurface extends SurfaceView implements     SurfaceHolder.Callback{
...//...
...//...

      public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
           boolean retry = true;
           thread.setRunning(false); ////// Нужно добавить эту строку!///////
           while(retry){
              try{
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
              }catch(InterruptedException e){}
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Вообще не стоит делать экраном приложения вьюху, так обычно поступают при разработке игр, и если у вас при запуске из ADT всё норм, то это наврятли связано с запуском через кнопку, а если и связано, то тут уже проблемы могу быть с манифестом. А ошибку не кидает? Если кидает, то покажите лог. А если у вас не возникает проблем при добавлении Layout, то нафига вы шаманите, просто добавьте layout, который будет содержать вашу въюху и всё.

Вижу у вас в коде, что вы не передаёте атрибуты в вашей View, а это необходимо. `DrawSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){ super(context, attrs); }`

Comment: `а это необходимо.` - нет, это **не** необходимо, т. к. `DrawSurface` создается только через конструктор с одинм параметром, и не используется в xml. `так обычно поступают при разработке игр` - мне кажется, что это именно такой случай.

Comment: > так обычно поступают при разработке игр.-- Это и будет игра.

Comment: Ситуация немного прояснилась. Когда я закрываю свое приложение на телефоне нажимая на кнопку(стрелочка назад). Потом захожу в телефоне в Настройки->Приложения->Сторонние->Мое приложение(О приложении)->Остановить(нажимаю кнопку). Выскакивает сообщение "Принудительная оcтановка" -> жму Ок.  После такого закрытия приложения, если я его опять запускаю с телефона,то все Ок запускается. А если так в ручную не останавливать, то кидает ошибку при запуске. Но так же не годиться   в ручную каждый раз лезть в настройки и его останавливать

Comment: @Денис7371 А лог ошибки скинуть можете?